# Процедура перемещения

Tags: delphi

Как в делфи сделать процедуру перемещения файла с одной папки в другую?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть функция:

```
MoveFile(lpExistingFileName: PAnsiChar; lpNewFileName: PAnsiChar): LongBool;
```

Answer (score 1):

Эта процедура уже есть. Она называется [MoveFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) и является заимпортированной WinAPI-функцией.